# Sugar metabolism in preserved/cryopreserved livestock semen

Tags: reproduction, enzymes

I wonder how can semen use di/tri-saccharide (e.g. sucrose, trehalose, raffinose) for spermatozoa metabolism in preservation/cryopreservation of livestock semen, since the semen itself never bring any enzyme to breakdown those sugars and the extender used also don't contain enzyme needed?

Is there any other way to breakdown sugar without enzyme, or is there any component in the extender which can substitute the enzyme function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The sugars that you mention are primarily used as a "cryoprotectant" and thus to reduce physical damage to the cells while frozen.  The sugars are not used to provide energy to the sperm as the enzymes will not function in the temperatures and conditions of a frozen environment. The addition of sugars is typically used with other types of cells/tissues in their cryopreservation as well.  The abstract in the link below summarized this.

https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/raq.12195